# Fetch out of sequence in coldfusion fw1 application

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I am working on a coldfusion fw1 application and am trying to get all records in a table greater than a certain date.

- START_DATE is a varchar not a date.
- The query works if I type it directly into Oracle Sql Developer.
- I have tried using the cfqueryparam tag but get the same error.
- The query is located in a service.

`<cfargument name = "studyType" default="null">
    <cfset minDate = '12/31/99'>
    <cfset maxDate = '01/01/55'> 
    <cfquery name="summaryInformation" datasource="#application.dsStudy#">
       select 
        START_DATE
       from RPTS_STUDY
       where TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'MM/DD/YY') >= TO_DATE('#minDate#', 'mm/dd/yy')
    </cfquery>`

Error:

```
[Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `'#minDate#'` with `'12/31/99'`? In one mask you're using `MM/DD/YY` while in the other you're using `mm/dd/yy`); is this a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: I also wonder why you're bothering with `TO_DATE()` at all. I'd expect `WHERE START_DATE >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#minDate#">` would work just fine. (You might need `cf_sql_timestamp` instead of `cf_sql_date`.)

Comment: I am more of a SQL Server guy, but just to confirm - that is the *exact* query throwing the error? Also, what is the context? ie Are there any other queries or transactions in the script?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Isn't TO_DATE a format function converting a string to a date object? in which case it IS necessary if you want to do a date comparison. Otherwise the comparison would be alpha.

Comment: Fish-START_DATE is not a date its a varchar. Leigh-There are no other queries in the script and I get a debug log that sends me to this specific query

Comment: Wierd because fetch out of sequence seems more of a cursor error. RPTS_STUDY is just a table right?

Comment: @Mark- Yes its just a table. Fish-Changing the case to MM/DD/YY did not fix the issue.

Comment: *RE: log that sends me to this specific query* When you say "sends you to that query" does it actually *show* that query or does it just point to a line number *near* it? The reason for asking is that error line numbers are not always accurate.

Comment: @Leigh It shows the query that caused the error. This is the only query for this page.

Comment: @christaba1116 - Okay. Then unfortunately, I am out of ideas. My limited understanding is that error usually involves transactions, cursors or things like select .. for update. But if that is the only query involved, and there are no transactions, I am not sure what to think.